# Excel VBA のVLOOKUPで、他のファイル参照

Tags: vba, excel

Excel VBAで、VLOOKUPを使って、他のファイルを参照する場合、①なら動きますが、②では上手く動きません。
②のような書き方は出来ないのでしょうか？

```
Sub Supply_Check()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells(1, 3).End(xlDown).Row

①    Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(LastRow, 8)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'C:\Users\user1\Documents\[支給部品.xlsx]Sheet1'!RC[-7]:R[18]C[-4],2,FALSE)"

②    Dim File_Path As String
    File_Path = "C:\Users\user1\Documents\[支給部品.xlsx]Sheet1"
    Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(LastRow, 8)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],File_Path!RC[-7]:R[18]C[-4],2,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File_Path`という変数が文字列としてくくられているため、
`File_Path = "C:\Users\user1\Documents\[支給部品.xlsx]Sheet1"`が認識されていないと
思います。(File_Pathという文字そのままになっている)

テストしてみたところ、下記なら動きそうですが、いかがでしょうか。

```
Range(Cells(2, 8), Cells(LastRow, 8)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-5],'" & File_Path & "'!RC[-7]:R[18]C[-4],2,FALSE)"
```